# Probability and Statistics (Normal Distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics

Having trouble with the last part of this question. Not sure how the man would divide his pile of vouchers? It seems that you could interpret this question in a lot of ways.
Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks :)

> A petrol company issues a voucher with every 10 litres of petrol that
>   a customer buys. Customers who send 50 vouchers to Head Office are
>   entitled to a free gift but only one gift is allowed per household.
>   After this promotion has been running for some time the company
>   receives several hundred bundles of vouchers in each day’s post. It
>   would take a long time, and hence not be cost effective, for someone
>   to count each bundle and so they decide to weigh them instead. Working
>   on the basis that the weight of a single voucher is a Normal variable
>   with mean 36mg and standard deviation 2.5mg they decide to calculate
>   the weight which will be exceeded by 95% of the bundles and only count
>   the numbers of vouchers in bundles which weigh less than this
>   calculated amount. A man has 150 vouchers, divides these into 3
>   bundles without checking the number in each bundle carefully, and
>   sends one claim for a gift in his own name and two claims in the names
>   of friends. Assess the probability that he will receive all three free
>   gifts using relevant calculations. Give details of any additional
>   assumptions that you have made.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to get you going...note that the last part of the question is forcing you to come up with some assumptions, so there isn't likely one answer:

The weight of the "reference pile" ($W_r$) used by the company will be distributed:

$$P_r\sim \mathcal{N}(50\times 36,50\times 2.5^2)=\mathcal{N}(1800,312.5)\implies \sigma_{W_r}\approx17.7$$

Therefore, their lower 5% cutoff is simply $1800-1.64\sigma\approx1,771$

Now, the man is making three piles which will contain$N_1,N_2,N_3$ cards such that $N_1+N_2+N_3=150$.

The weights of the piles will be $W_1,W_2,W_3$, where $W_i\sim \mathcal{N}(36N_i,2.5^2N_i)$

Thus, you need to come up with an assumption on the random process that generates the piles, then the probability of getting all three prizes is:

$$P(\cap_{i=1}^3W_i\geq1,771)=\sum P(N_1=n_1,N_2=n_2,N_3=n_3)P(\cap_{i=1}^3W_i\geq1,771|N_1=n_1,N_2=n_2,N_3=n_3)$$

The key to this problem is coming up with a model for $(N_1,N_2,N_3)$ that is both reasonable and simple....otherwise  you'll have a real task ahead of you.

Welcome to the world of probabilistic modelling.